# Kendo UI AngularJS ngmap autocomplete issue

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, kendo-ui, google-places-api

I m trying to integrate [ngmap](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!places-auto-complete.html) autocomplete with Kendo UI. But `placeChanged` event not firing. and autocomplete widget not showing. Input placeholder working. and I checked network. its getting predictions. but not showing.

Answer (score 0):

its was css issue . its fix my error.

```
.pac-container {
    z-index: 100000;
}
```